# scala program search for the most recent values

Tags: scala, apache-spark, bigdata

I want to create a df based on a hive sql below:

```
WITH FILTERED_table1 AS (select *
, row_number() over (partition by key_timestamp order by datime DESC) rn
FROM table1)

scala function:
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

val table1 = Window.partitionBy($"key_timestamp").orderBy($"datime".desc)
```

I looked into the window function and that was what I can come up with, I am not sure how to write this in scala function as I am very new to scala. how do I return a df from the sql use scala functions?
any suggestions will be greatly appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Window spec is correct.  Using a dummy dataset, let's first load your original Hive table into a DataFrame:

```
val df = spark.sql("""select * from table1""")

df.show
// +-------------+-------------------+
// |key_timestamp|             datime|
// +-------------+-------------------+
// |            1|2018-06-01 00:00:00|
// |            1|2018-07-01 00:00:00|
// |            2|2018-05-01 00:00:00|
// |            2|2018-07-01 00:00:00|
// |            2|2018-06-01 00:00:00|
// +-------------+-------------------+
```

To apply the Window function `row_number` (over the Window spec) to the DataFrame, use `withColumn` to generate a new column to capture the function result:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val window = Window.partitionBy($"key_timestamp").orderBy($"datime".desc)

val resultDF = df.withColumn("rn", row_number.over(window))

resultDF.show
// +-------------+-------------------+---+
// |key_timestamp|             datime| rn|
// +-------------+-------------------+---+
// |            1|2018-07-01 00:00:00|  1|
// |            1|2018-06-01 00:00:00|  2|
// |            2|2018-07-01 00:00:00|  1|
// |            2|2018-06-01 00:00:00|  2|
// |            2|2018-05-01 00:00:00|  3|
// +-------------+-------------------+---+
```

To verify, run your SQL against `table1` and you should get the same result:

```
spark.sql("""
    select *, row_number() over
      (partition by key_timestamp order by datime desc) rn
    from table1
  """).show
```